# Deploy Chrome Extension in Linux platform using group policy like method

Tags: linux, google-chrome-extension, group-policy

We created one chrome extension application and hosted it in the Chrome Store. Now, one of our customers doesn't want their user to download the chrome extension from the store. so, they need ***group policy*** distribution so that, the admin(master) will push the chrome extension to their users underneath it. But the problem is that customer use the ***Linux platform*** (both admin and all other users). Implementing the group policy in Linux seems not possible (correct me if I am wrong).

It would be helpful if anyone suggests some methods to deploy Chrome extension through group policy like method in the Linux platform.

Comment: What makes you think it's not possible? Did you see the [documentation](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7517525?hl=en)?

Comment: @wOxxOm - Thanks for the link. I have gone through all details in that documentation. The thing still I am not clear is like where we need to give the list of users to whom the Chrome extension needs to install. My apology if this sounds silly.